# Is there a front derailer clamp diameter that is near 29.6 or 29.7mm?

Tags: derailleur, derailleur-front, schwinn

I have a 1966 Schwinn Super Sport that I bought without a front derailer. The seat tube clamp diameter (i.e., the diameter measured out outside the seat tube, where a derailer would go) is ~29.6mm. [Sheldon](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/front-derailers.html) says the standards are 1 1/8" (28.6 mm) and 1 1/4" (31.8 mm).

Am I correct in assuming this is some Schwinn-specific diameter that predates those standards? I'm sure I could shim on a 1-1/4 in derailer, but I just want to make sure I'm not missing something obvious that would fit without shimming.

Comment: How did you measure the tube?  Its notoriously hard to measure such things with a ruler.  A flexible tape works if you measure the circumference and divide by pi.  But a vernier caliper works best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Saint Sheldon was right, but elsewhere.  http://www.sheldonbrown.com/schwinn-braze.html says under *1962 to 1978: Schwinn Fillet Brazing In the Bicycle Boom*

> The fillet-brazed CrMo frame construction of Schwinn's second class of lightweight bicycles - the Superior, Sports Tourer and **Super Sport** - was unique. The production flow for these bicycles began with frame fabrication in the handbuild part of the Chicago Schwinn factory; a low-volume production area. Frame tubes were mitered in a jig by machine, and then the remaining fabrication work (brazing, filleting, braze-ons, and finishing) was done by hand. The **seat and down tubes**, as well as the top tube on the largest frame sizes, are slightly oversize at **29.5 mm** in diameter. Schwinn called this tubing "1 1/8 inch diameter."

You will be hard-pressed to find a new FD for cheap these days.    Modern components tend to be more 31.8 or 34.9 mm.

Your best option will be to find a used 28.6mm on ebay and carefully file the clamp to fit your tube profile.  A 25.4mm FD would just need a lot more filing to achieve the same fit.

A less-pretty option would be a 31.8mm clamp and then shim it out with a lot of additional material, but that will be uglier, and potential flex under tension will make shifting worse.

You could also use a braze-on adapter and a separate FD mech.

Comment: A proper schwinn part labelled as 1 1/8"  might be your best buy - something like  https://www.ebay.com/itm/332666485917 should already be oversized.

Comment: Lovely. Really what I was asking was "what do I have to search for on eBay to find the right derailer for this bike", but you one-upped that! Order that part on eBay. Thanks for your help!